# How to resolve Fragment not attached to activity yet?

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube

I'm using a class that extends AppCompatDialogFragment, class code:

```
public class YoutubeDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private static View rootView;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
YoutubeDialogFragment() {

}

public static YoutubeDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
    YoutubeDialogFragment youtubeDialogFragment = new YoutubeDialogFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("title", title);
    youtubeDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return youtubeDialogFragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.general_pop_up_youtube, container, false);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

The layout general_pop_up_youtube includes a fragment, I'm trying to get that fragment using getChildFragmentManager(), but it always keeps throwing the following exception:

```
RuntimeException: Fragment has not been attached yet.
```

And I initiate the fragment using this code:

```
YoutubeDialogFragment popupYouTubePlayerFragment = YoutubeDialogFragment.newInstance("Title");

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

                popupYouTubePlayerFragment.show(fragmentManager.beginTransaction(), "youtube");

                popupYouTubePlayerFragment.getChildFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance(), "youtube_frag")
                        .commit();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: why do you have unnecesary contructor? and why do you have view in static field?

Comment: 1) Where are trying to "get that fragment using `getChildFragmentManager()`"? Post this code. 2) Also post the full stack trace for the error, it tells you exactly where the problem occurs. 3) You are creating a new fragment here `.add(YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance(), "youtube_frag")` use your existing fragment `.add(popupYouTubePlayerSupportFragment, "youtube_frag")` 4) Odds are good that you simply need to call your code in `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: 1: because i don't know who else i can get it

Comment: 3: I need to add a new YoutubePlayerSupportFragment into the fragment *not* my YoutubeDialogFragment.

Comment: Could you elaborate on in which class and in which method you try to get fragment manager (the bottom snippet)?

Comment: you know what I have to rephrase the question